# Initializing an asp.net deployment

Tags: asp.net

I have a basic webforms asp.net site. Currently its working on pre-created sql tables and I have to manually triger it to update data. Moving towards a live deployment though, I'd like to make it more comfortable.

How would I make it so that whenever the server software loads it up, the first thing it does before accepting any requests is to run an initialization sub? Just so I can make sure all the tables are there and if not I would create them etc.

Also, I'd like to run another sub that would trigger the data update periodically every few hours. I was thinking that if I could get my initialization sub, I could just spawn a background thread to deal with that but if theres a built-in option, I'll take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever the server software loads it up

In asp.net, you have the `global.asax` file - open the code behind for that and look at the possible overrides.  Among them will be:

```
protected void Application_Start()
```

This always runs when the application starts up and you could use this to check the DB.

If you're in an "in-house" environment where there's a single live database server and a single live application server, then it should be ok to assume that the database is deployed before the application and you won't need this.  If you're providing an application to a third-party or providing it on the web, then this is a good place to check.  How you generate the DB is up to you, but checking here is a good idea.  You could also have a (hidden) admin page on your site that checks the database connection etc.

> trigger the data update periodically

This won't be built-in to asp.net as asp.net waits for requests and responds to them.  There are ways around this, but generally triggered externally to the application.  The easiest is a simple windows scheduled task that hits a page to trigger the check.

Comment: I don't have a global.asax file though, I started the page as an empty project. Do I just create it then? Also, instead of triggering the update through a request to a special page, couldn't I just start a thread in Application_Start() that would do it for me?

Comment: Been a while, but something like: right click project in solution explorer, add file, look for global.asax in the list (probably under web).   Don't just add a file as there's `global.asax` and `global.asax.cs` and they need to be added to the project as a pair.

Comment: "started the page as an empty project" - did you start it as an empty *web* project?  If not, try creating a new project as a website and see what you get (not suggesting you start from scratch, just have a look)

Comment: Assuming you're hosting in IIS, IIS refreshes it's application pools so you can't guarantee that your thread will still be there.  I'm not sure of other arguments against, but it sounds like a bad architectural choice, maybe it's ok?

Answer (score 0):

This is what's referred to as "deployment".

If your web site is deployed via MSI, this step should be done in MSI.

If your web site is deployed via Visual Studio "publish" option, this is where you need to create tables.

Some applications indeed do as you say, e.g.: create SQL tables on the 1st run. The problem with this approach is that your app will need sa rights, instead or simple read/write. This could lead to security issues.

Code which runs on web site launch (which is where initialization belongs to) is located in global.asax in:

```
protected void Application_Start()
```